# Calculating power needed for a mercury-vapor bulb

Tags: solar-cell, inverter

I'm really trying to learn this stuff on my own, but I need some help...
First I'm going to be trying to charge a battery with a 15W solar panel, whose output is DC 5V/2.1 A - how would I calculate the length of time it would take to get it fully-charged? The battery is 98 Wh, 8800 mAh, 11V. 
Then, would it be possible to run a 160W mercury-vapor bulb (1.63 Arms) from it? I have a 110V inverter for the battery; 0.9A/100W max.
Thank you very much - I would like to see the workflow for this type of calculation so I can be off and running on my own!!
best,
Eric

Comment: sounds like a homework problem, possibly middle school level?

Comment: If the solar panel only produces 5 volts, it can't charge an 11 volt battery.  To charge a battery, the charging source must have a higher voltage than the fully-charged battery.

Answer (score 1):

Watts = Volts x Amps. Wh = Watts x hours. Your 'solar panel' can (perhaps) generate 5V x 2.1A = 10.5W. 98Wh / 10.5W = 9.3 hours. That would be at least two days of typical sunlight.

To charge your '11V' battery you need a battery charger designed for your battery type (lithium-ion?) and nominal voltage (11.1V?). The charger wastes some power (perhaps 20%) and probably needs a higher voltage to operate from, so you may need a voltage booster which wastes more power (another 20%?). So in practice it will probably take ~15 hours or 3 days to charge your battery (if you don't use it in the mean time).

Your 100W inverter can output 100W **maximum**. But your lamp **needs** 160W. So you will need a more powerful inverter.

The inverter wastes some power (20%?) so the battery will have to deliver ~20% more power than the lamp needs, ie. 192W. 192W / 11.1V = 17.3A. If your battery isn't rated for this much current then you will not be able to run your lamp from it.

Assuming your battery *can* deliver 17A, it would theoretically last 98Wh / 192W = 0.5 hours or 30 minutes. In practice you might get 80% of the rated capacity ie. 24 minutes - after charging the battery on the solar panel for 3 days.